# How to transclude <noinclude> tags in templates to set categories only on original page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

As part of a template, I'd like to set the category of a page. But also to have that category no included when that page is transcluded.

So if I have a template definition for Template:Person

```
<includeonly>Name: {{{1|}}}
[[Category:People]]
</includeonly>
```

Then in the person page of "John Smith", which adds John Smith to the People category as wanted

```
{{Person|John Smith}}
```

But then I have a page that transcludes the John Smith page but I don't want it in the category People. So say a page "Employee of the Week" has

```
== Best employee ever ==
{{:John Smith}}
```

Now I have a feeling it can be done with `{{subst:}}` or `{{safesubst:}}` as documented here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Substitution but I cannot figure it out

Now I see wikipedia has a template that looks like it does what I want, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Noinclude but I cannot figure it out and it isn't working for me. One of the things I tried was adding the `noinclude` and `dtag` templates to my wiki and then trying this for Template:Person, but it didn't work

```
<includeonly>Name: {{{1|}}}
{{subst:noinclude|[[Category:People]]}}
</includeonly>
```

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible without `{{subst:Person|John Smith}}`, which then expands the template in the person page where the template may add `<noinclude>` tags around the category.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<includeonly>Name: {{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}
{{#ifeq:{{PAGENAME}}|{{{1|{{PAGENAME}}}}}|[[Category:People]]}}</includeonly>
```

The parser function `{{#ifeq:}}` is provided by the extension [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##ifeq) bundled with *MediaWiki*. It compares the first two arguments and returns the third, if they are equal, the fourth otherwise.

The assumption is the the page name will be the same as the parametre of the template; or defined by the parametres, if the real template is more complex than the example.

Comment: Good idea, I wouldn't use the default though. This means writing `{{Person}}` on "John Doe" would work, but if you then include `{{:John Doe}}` elsewhere it will render "*Name: Employee of the Week*" (and include it in the category).

Comment: I like this idea, I'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: @Bergi, fair enough. Using defaults is my habit, while transcluding non-template pages is not.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a more complicated solution that works for me. I first installed the Variables extension, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables

Then created a template `Template:SetCategories`

```
<includeonly>{{#varexists:hidecats||{{#arraymap:{{{names|}}}|,|x|[[Category:x]]|}}}}</includeonly>
```

Then I (already had) a transclusion template `Template:IncludePageWithHeader` so I added a variable when a page is transcluded `{{#vardefine:hidecats|yes}}`

```
<includeonly>{{#switch: {{{heading_level|}}}
| 2 = == [[{{{name|}}}{{#if: {{{extra|}}}|,&#32;{{{extra|}}}|}}|{{{name|}}}]] ==
| 3 = === [[{{{name|}}}{{#if: {{{extra|}}}|,&#32;{{{extra|}}}|}}|{{{name|}}}]] ===
| 4 = ==== [[{{{name|}}}{{#if: {{{extra|}}}|,&#32;{{{extra|}}}|}}|{{{name|}}}]] ====
| === [[{{{name|}}}{{#if: {{{extra|}}}|,&#32;{{{extra|}}}|}}|{{{name|}}}]] ==
}}
{{#vardefine:hidecats|yes}}
{{:{{{name|}}}{{#if: {{{extra|}}}|,&#32;{{{extra|}}}|}}}}</includeonly>
```

So now `Template:Person` becomes

```
<includeonly>Name: {{{1|}}}
{{SetCategories|names=People}}
</includeonly>
```

And then Employee of the week becomes

```
{{IncludePageWithHeader|name=John Smith}}
```